# C++ include vs forward declaration strategy

Tags: c++, class, include, forward-declaration

Consider two well-known rules of thumb in C++:

- Use automatic objects wherever possible to benefit from RAII
- Use forward declarations instead of actual includes where possible to reduce compilation time and number of dependencies

Let's assume that I have the following class in C++:

```
class D {
  // some methods
  A a; B b; C c;
};
```

Following 1st rule of thumb I should keep all three automatic objects and add includes:

```
#include <A.h>
#include <B.h>
#include <C.h>
class D {
  // some methods
  A a; B b; C c;
};
```

Thus I increase compilation time because a lot of extra headers get into scope when I include `D.h`

Following second rule I should do the following:

```
class A; class B; class C;
class D {
  // some methods
  A *a; B *b; C *c;
};
```

But in this case I have to manage creation/deletion of objects myself, which we know often leads to errors and memory leaks.

Is there a solution for this problem? Using private implementation classes is a pain I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: You could use std::unique_ptr<A> a; and so on.

Comment: You shouldn't decide how to store member variables just based on include / forward declare convenience. You should actually consider if you class should *own* those members, or simply point-to/reference them.

Comment: You can use Unique_ptr to avoid self memory management. boost gives this interface. similar to garbage collector in java. unique_ptr will destroy itself when not referenced anymore.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know stl managed pointers don't require full class declaration. Thank you!

Comment: There is no good answer. You have to balance core data-types and local data-types (local in the context of a class or function). Hence you get a range of a core functionally change (with complete recompilation) and a local change (with tiny compile time costs). Anyway, you should keep forwards dependencies in a single header (avoid multiple forward declaration of the same)

Comment: "Using private implementation classes is a pain I'd like to avoid if possible" But this is exactly the problem the Pimpl idiom is intended to solve...

Comment: You should spell better.  Your examples won't compile. ;-)

Comment: You may be able to gain some build time by placing header guard checks inside the D `inlcude` file:  `#ifndef A_H #inlcude "a.h" #endif`.  This prevents the compiler from opening a file, reading the file until the `#endif` statement.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: This is actually very bad advice. Compilers are doing this kind of automatization since the mid-90's (making the non-standard but then-popular `#pragma once` obsolete), and besides, you are making assumptions about the actual naming of the header guard inside `a.h` (which might change, leaving you with really strange error messages). Premature optimization at its best (worst?).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, thanks, fixed some of the spelling errors indeed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I assume that you're strictly talking about the case where `D` owns the child object instances) This seems subjective, so a somewhat opinion-based answer: Use automatic objects and if the corresponding headers are so big that compilation times get noticeably longer, fix *that* problem.